# Why getting "Apps aren't loaded yet." error when import app models to another app in django

Tags: python, django, import, model

In a django project, I try to import classes from my app 'catalog' into another app named 'planning'. In the app 'planning', there's a python script that do query to MySQL DB defined in 'catalog' app. However, still getting the django error: **django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet**

For the discussion herein, I simplified the projet path to '...' and projet name to "project_name"

I looked several stackoverflow posts related to that similar issue, but none of the proposed solutions work in my case. Somebody know what I miss? (I'm using PyCharm community)

• All apps in INSTALLED_APPS

• virtualenv activated

• all `__init__.py` files are empty

• no circular relation between the apps 'catalog' and 'planning'

• I added the following in the environment variables:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project_name.settings
```

• I tried to execute from a standalone script

> exec(open('.../run_script.py).read())

• I tried adding the following script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    import sys, os, django
    path = "path/to/project"
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)
    from django.conf import settings
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
    django.setup()
    main()
```

The only way I was able to import the 'catalog' app w/o error and do query from 'planning' app is manually through:

> python manage.py shell

Here's the traceback obtained from every attempts above

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../planning/models.py", line 25, in <module>
    from catalog.models import VarietyData
  File "...\catalog\models.py", line 228, in <module>
    class Author(models.Model):
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 103, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 135, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

At the end, I want to be able to import app within another one from the same django project and being able to execute/test python script while developping the app.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: When are you getting this error? You say `manage.py shell` works fine. Is this when running `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: It was when I run the model from PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved my issue. I'll leave the question posted w/ the following simple answer in case it may help somebody else...

The

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

was written in the app "planning.models", where the import statement gave the afored error. Instead, by setting the execution entry point script out of the app, directly into a separate .py file at the project level, everthing work fine!